# How can I pingpong between two values -3 and 3 slowly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update()
    {
        float slow = Mathf.PingPong(Time.deltaTime * 5, 6);
        material.SetFloat("_DissolveAmount", slow);
    }
```

The starting value of the _DissolveAmount is -3 and I want it to pingpong between -3 and 3 slowly not to make a pingpong every X seconds but that the values changing will be slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) returns values between `0` and given `length`.

You already pass in `6` so you only need to shift it back by `-3`.

Or as alternative use [`Mathf.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) and use `PingPong` from `0` to `1` as factor to be more flexible.

You are also passing in `Time.deltaTime * 5` but `PingPong` expects an absolute time value as input so rather use `Time.time`.

> `PingPong` requires the value `t` to be a **self-incrementing** value, for example `Time.time`, and `Time.unscaledTime`.

By multiplying it with 5 you make it 5 times faster .. if you want it slow you probably rather want to divide like

```
// only needed if using Lerp
public float minValue = -3;
public float maxValue = 3;

public float durationInSeconds = 5;

void Update()
{
    var value = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time / durationInSeconds, 6) - 3;
    // Or using Lerp
    //float value = Mathf.Lerp(minValue, maxValue, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time / durationInSeconds, 1));
    material.SetFloat("_DissolveAmount", value);
}
```

---

As for how to fade once from -3 to 3

I would use a Coroutine like

```
private bool alreadyFading;

IEnumerator FadeOnce(float from, float to, float duration) 
{ 
    alreadyFading = true;

    var timePassed = 0f; 
    while(timePassed < duration)
    { 
        var factor = timePassed / duration; 
        var value = Mathf.Lerp(from, to, factor; 

        material.SetFloat("_DissolveAmount", value); 

       yield return null; 
   } 

    material.SetFloat("_DissolveAmount", to); 

    alreadyFading = false;
}
```

And call it like e.g.

```
public void Fade()
{
    if(!alreadyFading) StartCoroutine (FadeOnce(-3, 3, 5f);
}
```

Comment: Working great. and if I want to use Lerp to make the value change from -3 to 3 only once?

Comment: Then you should rather use a Coroutine like `IEnumerator FadeOnce(float from, float to, float duration) { var timePassed = 0f; while(timePassed < duration){ var factor = timePassed / duration; var value = Mathf.Lerp(from, to, factor; material.SetFloat("_DissolveAmount", value); yield return null; } material.SetFloat("_DissolveAmount", to); }`